# Configuring middleware using Ruby on Rails 4

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, omniauth, ruby-on-rails-4, rack

I am interested in using OmniAuth CAS in my Ruby on Rails 4 project. The particular gem I'm looking at is this one: https://github.com/dlindahl/omniauth-cas

the documentation says to configure CAS with an excerpt that looks like the following:

```
Rails.application.config.middleware.use OmniAuth::Builder do
  provider :cas, host: 'cas.yourdomain.com'
end
```

my question is simply where would this go in the context of a Ruby on Rails 4 application? What file would the config get placed in? Does anything additional need to be done to use middleware in Ruby on Rails 4? I tried adding the following in my `application.rb`, but getting complaints that no route matches [GET] "/cas_login":

```
config.middleware.use OmniAuth::Builder do
        provider :cas, login_url: 'http://localhost:3000/cas_login', host: 'localhost', port: 3000
    end
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This code should be placed in an initializer at `config/initializers/cas_middleware.rb`.

Alternatively, you could put this syntax inside the class of your `config/application.rb` block:

```
config.middleware.use OmniAuth::Builder do
  provider :cas, host: 'cas.yourdomain.com'
end
```

And it would do just the same thing.

Comment: Thanks Ryan. I guess I should open a new thread looking for help on why the appropriate route(s) haven't been created after I added that middleware.